# Show/hide class depending on if there is a vertical scrollbar or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm new to jQuery and have been trying to get this to work but have been unsuccessful.  I can get portions of my code working, but haven't been able to get it all working together.

On my website, I have an up and down arrow (both inside a single parent class) that will scroll to the top/bottom of the page when clicked -- I have this working already using jQuery.

However, I ***only*** want these arrows to be displayed ***if*** there's actually anything to scroll (i.e. if there's a scrollbar present);  otherwise I want them to be hidden.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

That code above will return true or false depending on the presence of a scrollbar, but I haven't been able to get it working with my function (I don't have to use that code, it's just what I found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onresize=arrows;
window.onload=arrows;

function arrows(){
if(document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight){
document.getElementById("arrow").style.display="block";
}else{
document.getElementById("arrow").style.display="none";
}
}
```

Not jquery but its working (or not :))

Comment: Hmm I wasn't able to get this working.  Should it show/hide the ID depending on if there's a scrollbar present?

Comment: Ive corrected some mistakes ive made. And yes it displays the element with the arrow id.

Comment: Hmm I must be doing something wrong.  I should note that my arrows are actually using `display:fixed` though I tried making them `block` and couldn't get it working.  Is that exactly what the code would look like inside the <script> tags?

Comment: Im not next to a computer, so i cannot debug it. Does it print any errors??

Comment: Ah, it says ReferenceError:  body is not defined

Comment: I changed line 2. to document.body

Comment: Okay so, that's working a little more now, but there's two issues:  first, the arrows don't reappear _after_ they've been hidden (if you make the window smaller, then make it wider again).  Secondly, if the window starts without a scrollbar, the arrows will be shown, but instantly disappear if the user resizes the window.  I'm by no means an expert with JS or jQuery, but would it be easier with jQuery?

Comment: Oh sorry. Modified again.

Comment: The arrows now hide `onload` when there's no scrollbar (hooray!), but the resizing part still isn't working.  The arrows are shown when there _is_ a scrollbar, but after it disappears, it doesn't come back if the scrollbar reappears.  It's more code, but is it better to use an event listener instead of overriding the `onresize` or does it not matter? **EDIT** nevermind, I got it! Swapped `fixed` to `block` in your code, and it works.

Comment: I marked this as an accepted answer despite it not using jQuery, as it functions (using my edit noted above) and I'm using it.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :). ( I tought using Jquery in this small script is not good for loading time)

Answer (score -1):

I would use an event listener on `this.height.change(*your function here*)` and then use the return of that to fire off a function that would employ jQuery's [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to show/hide your scroll buttons